# Merge array of objects with an object using Object.assign

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm trying to merge array of objects which with an object using `Object.assign()`

```
var state = {
    items: [{
       id: "Harko",
       name: "Haris"
    },
    {
      id: "Benko",
      name: "Benjo"
    }]

}

var a = {
    id: "Benko",
    name: "Bengalka"
}
```

What I tried already:

```
Object.assign(state.items,a);
Object.assign({}, { items: [state.items,a]);
```

What I want to get is the following:

```
{
    items: [{
       id: "Harko",
       name: "Haris"
    },
    {
      id: "Benko",
      name: "Bengalka"
    }]
}
```

So I want that Object in var state with id "Benko" to be overwritten by var a, because they have same id.

Is this possible with Object.assign?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really do that at a top-level using `Object.assign`. What you need to do is [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object reference first, then you can use `Object.assign` to update it's properties:

```js
const state = {
    items: [{
       id: "Harko",
       name: "Haris"
    },
    {
      id: "Benko",
      name: "Benjo"
    }]

}

const a = {
    id: "Benko",
    name: "Bengalka"
}
const foundObject = state.items.find(obj => obj.id === a.id);
Object.assign(foundObject, a);
console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash merge() worked for my use case:

```
let v = {foo: [{change: "first", leave: "here"}]}
_.merge(v, {foo: [{change: "second"}]})
```

Value of v after merge:

```
{ foo: [{change: "second", leave: "here"}]
```

Compare to Object.assign() which will replace the first item in the array with the second:

```
Object.assign(v, {foo: [{change: "second"}]})
```

Value of v after (leave prop is missing):

```
{ foo: [{change: "second"}] }
```

Answer (score 0):

In additional to **Joseph Connolly** answer:
You can use [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) or [assignWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assignWith) methods from lodash with 3rd argument.
Example from lodash docs:

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue);
  }
}
 
var object = { 'a': [1], 'b': [2] };
var other = { 'a': [3], 'b': [4] };
 
_.mergeWith(object, other, customizer);
// => { 'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4] }
```